Как подставить переменную в запрос?
Подскажите пожалуйста что не так у меня в коде.
Делаю запрос в базу данных
$id = $_POST['id']; // 25
$cat = $_POST['thisCat']; // persons
$ph = \R::getAll("
    SELECT *
    FROM phones
    WHERE owner_id = $id AND cat = $cat
");

Получаю ошибку
Произошла ошибка
Код ошибки: Исключения ошибок
Текст ошибки: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'persons' in 'where clause'
Файл, в котором произошла ошибка: Z:\domains\a-my.loc\vendor\fw\libs\rb.php
Строка, в которой произошла ошибка: 720

но если в запросе вместо переменной $cat запрямую написать 'persons'
$ph = \R::getAll("
    SELECT *
    FROM phones
    WHERE owner_id = $id AND cat = 'persons'
");

всё работает.
Что я делаю не так?

Ну, видимо, при подстановке переменных persons в запрос подставляется без кавычек. Видимо, эти кавычки вам нужно вручную прописать. Ну или должен быть какой-то другой метод подстановки параметров в SQL запрос, который учитывает тип данных и сам ставит кавычки. Я просто не знаю как с этим в php дело обстоит.

@CrazyElf  в php с этим обстоит точно так же, как и в любом другом языке. Кавычки руками никто не ставит

@Ипатьев Ага, я уже нашёл вроде )

Где же вы этот древний RedBean достаёте-то.

А посоветуйте тогда что мне вместо этого древнего использовать?

Попробуйте использовать такую подстановку переменных:
$id = $_POST['id']; // 25
$cat = $_POST['thisCat']; // persons
$ph = \R::getAll("
    SELECT *
    FROM phones
    WHERE owner_id = :id AND cat = :cat
",
[
     'id' => $id,
     'cat' => $cat
]);


Получилось, спасибо.

@DGudush Если ответ вам помог, поставьте ему галочку )
